# AWS S3 Desabilitando suporte ao SSLv3

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-aws, boto

Eu recebi um email da AWS que diz basicamente que o S3 não vai mais dar suporte para SSLv3. Então eles listaram a lista de buckets que estão recebendo requests em SSLv3 e um dos meus buckets é de produção. O e-mail completo pode ser visto aqui:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4240c8af5208782c144c

Minha pergunta é: como posso testar esse cenário e o que preciso fazer para corrigir esse problema?

Eu uso Python 2.7, Django(1.4.20) e Boto(2.27.0)

Isso é apenas um problema de client ou algo que eu precise entender melhor e testar/corrigir?

Comment: Já efetuou a trocado protocolo das requisições que utilizam `SSLv3` para o uso do protocolo `S3 HTTPS Endpoints`, como dito no e-mail?

Comment: Onde deve ser efetuada essa troca? Na console de amazon ou na aplicação?

Comment: `To avoid interrupted access, you must update any client software (or inform any clients to update software) making the requests that are using SSLv3 to connect to S3 HTTPS endpoints.` -> Com base nessa linha, está especificando que a modificação deve ser feita na aplicação (software).

Comment: Mas como eu faço para testar se minha aplicação está fazendo as requisições via SSLv3 ou S3 HTTPS endpoints?

Comment: então S3 http endpoints não é um protocolo, é uma url que já está sem acesso por SSLv3 para que as pessoas testes o acesso das aplicações

Comment: Cara simples só ver qual o servidor que você está utilizando (tipo apache, nginx, etc) e desabilitar o suporte a SSLv3  aqui tem uma howto http://disablessl3.com/

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, é só trocar a URL que você está chamando na aplicação pela substituta mais atual dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto é problema apenas se você tem clientes que acessam S3 e não suportam TLS v1.0. Entre clientes velhos que caem neste grupo, encontram-se Android 2 e Java 6.

Tente rodar a ferramenta de testes www.SSLabs.com no seu domínio, ele faz um diagnóstico completo do seu SSL/TLS e inclusive lista com que clientes seu site é ou não é compatível.

Pelo que entendi o e-mail que você recebeu vale apenas para o S3. Se você está rodando um servidor em instância EC2, não se aplica porque quem implementa o SSL/TLS é o Django, não a Amazon.

Se você está usando diversas instâncias EC2 com ELB, a configuração SSL/TLS é feita no ELB, mas acho que ainda é configurável suportar SSLv3 no ELB (o default é desligado).

Comment: O "problema" já tinha sido resolvido, mas a sua resposta é bastante pertinente para a pergunta então vou marcar como correta :). No meu caso, nenhuma alteração foi feita por minha parte, após a alteração tudo continuou funcionando perfeitamente.